# Batch update/save documents in Truevault?

Tags: truevault

Is there a way to batch save/update documents in Truevault? The current documentation only shows how to save/update individual documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently TrueVault does not have a way to update multiple Documents in one API call. We are looking to add this functionality in the future.